# Colocar input fica abaixo do label

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como fazer para esse input ficar abaixo do label.

```css
.passo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #29b2fe;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.input {

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-margem">
    <h1 class="h2">Iniciando</h1>
  </div>

  <form action="">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="passo">1</span><label class="h3">Crie uma conta</label><br>
      <input id="email" class="input">
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Como assim em linha ? explica melhor o que pretendes, para nós conseguirmos te ajudar

Comment: Como assim "ficar em linha"?

Comment: Aqui já está em linha (inline)

Comment: @CianoBarbarossa Espressei erradamente, pensei em uma coisa e escrevi outra. Preciso que o input fique sempre abaixo do label. Esta ficando na frete.

Comment: @Dudaskank Espressei erradamente, pensei em uma coisa e escrevi outra. Preciso que o input fique sempre abaixo do label. Esta ficando na frete.

Comment: @13dev Espressei erradamente, pensei em uma coisa e escrevi outra. Preciso que o input fique sempre abaixo do label. Esta ficando na frete.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você precisa é que ele fique na linha de baixo você pode adicionar um `<br>` depois de `<label>`

```css
.passo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #29b2fe;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.input {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="passo">1</span><label class="h3">Crie uma conta</label><br>
    <input id="email" class="input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aqui funciona mas aqui na minha tela não. Acredito que deve ser algo do bootstrap que impede o `br`

Comment: @Tiago Estranho. Pode ser que seu navegador esteja guardando cache. Se estiver no Chrome, entre na sua pagina e aperte: CTRL + SHIFT + R

Comment: @Francisco Nada...rsrs

Comment: Que luta para uma tão simples....rsrs

Comment: Você está usando algum css pronto que você deixou de examinar?

Comment: Estou fazendo usando bootstrap

Comment: já tentou procurar lá no arquivo por um display:inline-block no seletor do input?

Answer (score 1):

Agora entendi rs, basta trocar a propriedade `display` do elemento. [Saiba mais sobre display.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```css
.input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="passo">1</span><label class="h3"> Crie uma conta</label><br>
        <input id="email" class="input">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Se aqui funciona e na sua página não, algum outro CSS está influenciando. Inspecione os elementos para tentar encontrar a causa do problema.

Comment: Coloquei, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

tenta usar o pseudoelemento **:before** para forcar uma quebra de linha

```css
.passo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #29b2fe;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

input:before {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="passo">1</span><label class="h3">Crie uma conta</label><br>
    <input id="email" class="input">
  </div>
</div>
```